# Tem como usar operadores lógicos com CASE/WHEN?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, when

Estou tentando usar operadores lógicos com CASE/WHEN no SQL porém estou tendo dificuldades, preciso apresentar uma resposta para caso o resultado da operação seja inferior a 0 e outro resultado para quando a operação seja >= 0

Dá erro se eu coloco um operador lógico ali:

```
CASE (A + B + C)
    **WHEN >= 0** THEN 'RESPOSTA'
    ELSE 'SEM RESPOSTA'
END AS RESULTADO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, você só precisa colocá-los direto no `WHEN`:

```
CASE
    WHEN (A + B + C) >= 0 THEN 'RESPOSTA'
    ELSE 'SEM RESPOSTA'
END AS RESULTADO
```

Comment: Valei cara consegui terminar a minha Query